# Unable to retrieve key:values, getting error --> jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index number with string

Tags: jq

Unable to extract key:value pairs, tried indexing the block.

```
<nd.com.citrix.netscaler.json" -X GET https://abcd.com/nitro/v1/config/lbpersistentsessions?args=vserver:puppet-vip.ta10.sd | jq '[.[] ] | .[3] | [.srcip]'
```

Getting the following error :

`jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "srcip"`

I need to extract the key:values as srcip and destip (see below)

```
<ion/vnd.com.citrix.netscaler.json" -X GET https://abcd.com/nitro/v1/config/lbpersistentsessions?args=vserver:somevip | jq '[.[] ] | .[3]' | more
[
  {
    "vserver": "somevip",
    "type": "1",
    "typestring": "SOURCEIP",
    "srcip": “1.1.1.1",
    "srcipv6": "::/0",
    "destip": "2.2.2.2",
    "destipv6": "::/0",
    "flags": false,
    "destport": 0,
    "vservername": “somevip”,
    "timeout": "0",
    "referencecount": "0",
    "persistenceparam": "1.1.1.1"
  },
```

I had to use [.3] to index as the original output is :

```
<-Type:application/vnd.com.citrix.netscaler.json" -X GET https://abcd.com/nitro/v1/config/lbpersistentsessions?args=vserver:somevip | jq '[.[] ]' | more
[
  0,
  "Done",
  "NONE",
  [
    {
      "vserver": "somevip",
      "type": "1",
      "typestring": "SOURCEIP",
      "srcip": “1.1.1.1”,
      "srcipv6": "::/0",
      "destip": "2.2.2.2",
      "destipv6": "::/0",
      "flags": false,
      "destport": 0,
      "vservername": "somevip",
      "timeout": "0",
      "referencecount": "0",
      "persistenceparam": "1.1.1.1"
    },
    {
      "vserver": "somevip",
      "type": "1",
      "typestring": "SOURCEIP",
      "srcip": "3.3.3.3”,
      "srcipv6": "::/0",
      "destip": "4.4.4.4”,
      "destipv6": "::/0",
      "flags": false,
      "destport": 0,
      "vservername": "somevip",
      "timeout": "0",
      "referencecount": "0",
      "persistenceparam": "1.1.1.1"
    },
```

Also, tried this way and get the error :

```
<GET https://abcd.com/nitro/v1/config/lbpersistentsessions?args=vserver:somevip | jq -r '.[] | select(.vserver == "somevip") | .srcip'
```

`jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index number with string "vserver"`

Comment: If you look at the syntax highlighting in the question you can see that you've used the wrong type of double quote around the `srcip` property in both examples. The `”` needs to be changed to `"`. In fact there's several other properties with the same problem. I'd suggest doing a find + replace.

Comment: That was just a copy/paste error. I was not using a proper text editor. i will correct the question.

Comment: hmm .. if i output this to a .json file and index, it works.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing some minor problems with the full JSON shown in the Q, the invocation:

```
jq '.[3][].srcip' input.json
```

yields:

```
"1.1.1.1"
"3.3.3.3"
```

### Notes

1. `.[3][].scrip` is just a shortened form of: `.[3] | .[] | .srcip`
2. In your initial query, `[.[]]` effectively does nothing because the input is an array.